# Run Script in Background Linux Server w/ PHP exec()

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to trigger a PHP script to run in the background using the exec() function but I cannot get it to work. I've read countless posts on stack overflow and other forums and tried many variations to no avail.

**Server Info:**

```
Operating System: Linux
PHP: 5.2.17 
Apache Version: 2.2.23
Home Directory: /home1/username
```

I'm currently using the code:

```
exec("/home1/username/php /home1/username/public_html/myscript.php > /dev/null &");
```

When I run the above script I get no error_log and no error in my cPanel error log, however the script definitely doesn't execute. When I browse to http://www.mydomain.com/myscript.php it runs and e-mails me instantly. Any idea why this isn't working / how I can find out what error is being produced?

**Update cPanel Process Manager Output**

```
exec("php /home1/username/php /home1/username/public_html/myscript.php > /dev/null &");
```

Produces:

```
27183   php /home1/username/php /home1/username/public_html/myscript.php
27221   [sh]
27207   php /home1/username/php /home1/username/public_html/myscript.php
27219   php /home1/username/php /home1/username/public_html/myscript.php
27222   php /home1/username/php /home1/username/public_html/myscript.php
27224   php /home1/username/php /home1/username/public_html/myscript.php
27249   sh -c php /home1/username/php /home1/username/public_html/myscript.php > /dev/null &
```

Is that normal? Script appears to hang around for a long time even though it should execute very quickly.

Comment: How are you running the exec()? From a shell script, another PHP file? Is your PHP really installed at /home/username/php?

Comment: I'm running it from another php script. Yeah in my FTP is shows as /php and my home dir is /home1/username. Any way to verify this?

Comment: I'm guessing you're running this under Apache? Does Apache have read+execute writes on the script and all the directories leading up to it?

Comment: Yes it does have the permissions to do so. Apache Version: 2.2.23

Answer (score 4):

Couldn't get the exec working with php. Even when I got shell access to the server the command just hung. I decided to use wget instead which accomplishes the same thing. Works great :)

```
exec("wget http://www.mydomain.com/myscript.php > /dev/null &");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried invoking the php CLI directly?

```
exec("php /home1/username/php /home1/username/public_html/myscript.php > /dev/null &");
```

You will not need the #!, which would output to the browser if called through Apache.

**EDIT**. 
It looks like your script is working, but your PHP script executing in the background is hanging (not exiting). Try this variation:

```
exec("php /home1/username/php /home1/username/public_html/myscript.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

[What does “> /dev/null 2>&1″ mean?](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/06/what-does-devnull-21-mean/)

Comment: when I ran that I just got a white page, no error no script run. Is there a way I can check for errors somehow? error_log is not being generated

Comment: maybe instead of /dev/null I can change it to see the output somehow?

Comment: Can you run that command directly on the command line? It sounds like you have a crash (blank page) and your error logging must be set too low. Is exec() even allowed by your host?

Comment: Sure, try sending to output to a file you can tail.

Comment: Not sure if it's a crash. When I run echo exec(whoami) it works fine. I just checked the Process Manager in my cPanel and I see some interesting activity after executing the above...I'll update my question with the output now

Comment: also when I refresh the process manager the Process ID's change a it jumps around

Comment: So the script is executing never ending. Can we see the code?

Comment: basically it runs a file_get_contents on a local file and then e-mails me an html e-mail of that file using php mail function. Worth mentioning that this script works fine when I visit it in browser to execute it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I'm running out of ideas. The web and CLI environments are different, so it suggests your code is good but something in the environment is throwing it off. I hope that helps, good luck.

Comment: I just ran myscript.php as a cron job which I think runs it in the background as well and it worked fine. Just wanted to rule that script out. Still looking to run it with exec()

Comment: Okay, good deal. Perhaps you need to redirect your script's stderr to /dev/null in addition to stdout to avoid it hanging. I think this is my last idea. :-)

Comment: Can you give an example? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Thanks, tried that but no luck :/ I'm baffled by this one..I'll try asking BlueHost if they have any suggestions either.

Answer (score 0):

since you want to run the `myscript` from your command line, wy not do this:

```
exec('(/home1/username/public_html/myscript.php) > /dev/null &',$r,$s);
```

And write this as a first line in the myscript.php:

```
#!/home1/username/php -n
<?php
    //script goes here
?>
```

That *should* work. The hashbang tells the system what programme to use to run the script that follows, so you don't need to add that to your `exec` call. Also, it's safer (and therefore better) to put brackets around the full script call, just so PHP knows what output has to be redirected to what stream, to avoid any issues that might occur. Especially when libs or packages like PHP-GTK are installed on the server (hence the `-n` option).

Comment: I tried that but it's the same issue. Doesn't run my script and doesn't output any error. Just a blank white page with no error_log file

Comment: @user1647347: What do you see when you add `var_dump($r);` and `echo $s;` just after the `exec` statement? if `$s !== 0`, there's a problem with the script you're calling... try it without redirecting the output to `/dev/null` first, bc you're effectively hiding the output with your code.

Comment: without the `/dev/null`-bit? are you sure that the php.ini is configured correctly, so that `mail` works as it should? By showing output I mean: do a regular `exec` call: (`exec('/path/to/script.php',$r,$s);`, and then echo the `$r` and `$s vaLs`

Comment: Yes - when I run the script directly it emails me instantly.

Comment: When you run it from the exec call? In which case, there's no issue, is there?

Comment: When I run from exec the script does not execute and no error is produced :/